# i don't understand, how to stick the last of the link on the sidebar to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, nuxt.js

I want to stick the last of the link on the sidebar to the bottom, like this.

[image: my example]

It is not difficult, while the height sidebar and main content are equal. If the content great that one screen last link of the sidebar is gone. I test it on https://codepen.io/deni5n/pen/QWKRmMj

I was trying to add position fixed, freeze height to 100vh, and z-index to the sidebar. It is worked, but if add many links, the last link is gone.

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="link-one">link One</div>
    <div class="link-two">link Two</div>
    <div class="link-three">link Three</div>
    <div class="link-footer">link Footer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html{
  heigth: 100%;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar{
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #313a46;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar .link-one{
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar [class^="link-"]:not(:first-of-type){
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar .link-footer{
  margin-top: auto;
  color: red;
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px
}

.content p:not(:first-of-type){
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

If you know, how to do this, please tell me

**UPDATE**

I still don’t know how to do it in html/css. However, since my NuxtJs project, I added to the class sidebar :style = "{'min-height': minHeight}, two hooks:

```
created() {
 this.handleDebouncedScroll = debounce(this.handleScroll, 100)
 window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleDebouncedScroll)
},

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleDebouncedScroll)
},
```

and methods:

```
handleScroll() {
  this.minHeight = `calc(100vh + ${window.scrollY}px)`
},
```

it's all. link-footer is now always at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You should use this.

Link: https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/xxENzmg

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.container{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.sidebar{
  max-width: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  background: #313a46;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: block;
  flex-direction: column;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
}

.sidebar .link-one{
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar [class^="link-"]:not(:first-of-type){
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.sidebar .link-footer{
  color: red;
}

.content{
  margin-left:210px;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px
}

.content p:not(:first-of-type){
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.goTop {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}

.goBottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="goTop">
    <div class="link-one">link One</div>
    <div class="link-two">link Two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="goBottom">
    <div class="link-three">link Three</div>
    <div class="link-footer">link Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab alias asperiores assumenda autem cumque dolore doloremque eligendi, esse est facere fugit laborum maiores mollitia nemo optio perferendis quae quas quibusdam quo quos ratione, rerum saepe sed tenetur voluptates! Aspernatur beatae delectus dolorum est exercitationem, obcaecati perspiciatis possimu
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it is the same as "margin auto": the last link hide if content do not fit on the screen

Comment: @deni5n what about now?

Comment: All the same ( I tried position: sticky, but it looks terrible ... I ended up postponing this part for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `justify-content` proprierty.

In the general, this propierty controls the spacing of the elements. So, basicly you need to agroup the *Link One* and *Link Two* in a div and in the father div, use a `justify-content: space-between;`.

```css
.father {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="header">
    <p>Content 1</p>
    <p>Content 2</p>
    <div>
      Another Content
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    Last content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the height of the sidebar might be great than 200px. I can not freeze the "height" XXXpx in the sidebar

Comment: You can use "height: 100%;"  too, I used 200px just for the example.

Answer (score 0):

change your following piece of code:

```html
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="link-one">link One</div>
    <div class="link-two">link Two</div>
    <div class="link-three">link Three</div>
    <div class="link-footer">link Footer</div>
  </div>
```

to look like following:

```html
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-main">
      <div class="link-one">link One</div>
      <div class="link-two">link Two</div>
      <div class="link-three">link Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <div class="link-footer">link Footer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and in the css, add the following styles:

```css
.sidebar{
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
  position: fixed; //change over here
  height: 100vh; //change over here
  background: #313a46;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; //change over here
  justify-content:space-between ; //change over here
}

.content{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 220px; //change over here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was trying to add a position fixed -> the last link is gone if add many links before (

Comment: @deni5n didn't get you, can you please rephrase it.

Comment: see https://codepen.io/deni5n/pen/QWKRmMj , last link do not fit on the screen

Comment: Lorem is just an example, imagine many nested ul li. On mobile, it is might easy do not fit on the screen